# The subextension of the 7th cyclotomic field of degree $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

The Galois group of the 7th cyclotomic field is $Z_6$, so it has a unique subgroup of degree $3$. Let $x = e^{\frac{2\pi i }{7}}$, then it is easy to say that $a = x^4+x^2+x$ is fixed by this subgroup. My question is how do I show that $x^4+x^2+x$ is not rational. That seems like an easy question, but I do not even know where to start since I cannot envision the concrete form of $x^4+x^2+x$.

Comment: Hint: consider $x^4+x^2+x$ and $x^6+x^5+x^3$ as the two roots of a quadratic equation.

Comment: That is magical! How do you come up with this though? @MarkBennet

Comment: Well there are reasons for this, but you do expect $a$ to be the root of a quadratic. Note that the complement can be written $x^{-1}+x^{-2}+x^{-4}$ which is equally fixed by the subgroup for the same reason. It is easy to see that the six powers must be distinct. Galois theory codifies the magic and tells you when to expect it.

Comment: Why should I expect it to be the root of a quadratic by Galois theory?

Comment: Can you probably write the reason as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: If you want to apply rather advanced number-theoretic considerations, you may use the facts that (1) the $7$-th cyclotomic field is ramified only above $7$, and (2) there is only one quadratic extension of $\Bbb Q$ that’s ramified only above $7$, namely $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-7}\,)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a neat trick here which I learned by accident.

Consider also the element $b=x^{-1}+x^{-2}+x^{-4}=x^6+x^5+x^3$, then $a$ and $b$ are roots of a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients and can be determined explicitly.

In an extension of degree $2$ over the rationals any element $\alpha$ which is not rational will generate the whole extension. Since the extension is of degree $2$ the elements $1, \alpha, \alpha^2$ cannot be linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ so $\alpha$ satisfies a quadratic polynomial. Clearing denominators gives a quadratic with integer coefficients. If $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer (and $a$ here is constructed to be such) then there will be a quadratic with leading coefficient $1$.

Note that $a+b=-1$ so that if $a$ is fixed under the various automorphisms you are considering, $b$ will be fixed too. And $b=-a-1$

Note also that the mundane procedure indicated above works here as well:

$$a^2=(x+x^2+x^4)^2=x^2+x^4+x^8+2(x^3+x^5+x^6)=a+2(-a-1)$$ so that $a^2+a+2=0$

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $p$ is an odd prime, then the $p$th cyclotomic field has, as its quadratic subextension, ${\bf Q}(\sqrt p)$ if $p\equiv1\bmod4$, and ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-p})$ if $p\equiv-1\bmod4$. Even more generally, there are similar formulas for the unique quadratic subextension of the $n$th cyclotomic field. These can be worked out from the Wikipedia pages on quadratic Gauss sums, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum

Answer (score 1):

This kind of question has been asked many times and admits a general answer. To keep it at hand, let me give a detailed explanation. For a given odd prime $p$, the cyclotomic field $F=\mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$ is a cyclic extension of $\mathbf Q$ of degree $p-1$. By the Galois correspondance, it contains a *unique* quadratic subfield $K$ which we can make explicit. To this end, let us compute the discriminant $D(F)$ using the formula $D(F)=N(f'(\zeta_p))$ , where $f$ is the minimal plynomial of $\zeta_p$ and $N$ is the norm of $F/\mathbf Q$ (this is valid for any simple extension $\mathbf Q(\alpha)/\mathbf Q$). Writing $(X-1)f'(X)=pX^{p-1}$, we get immediately $D(F)=\pm p^{p-2}$, with $+$ holding iff $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$ (see e.g. D. Marcus, "Number Fields", chap.2, ex.8). Recalling that $D(F)$ is a square in $F$ and using the uniqueness of $K$, we get $K=F(\sqrt {p^*})$, where $p^*=(-1)^{\frac {p-1}2}p$ . In your example here, $K=\mathbf Q(\sqrt {-7})$.

NB: The ramification criterion used by @Lubin amounts to the computation of $D(F)$.